# Is there any way to do calculate the MAX() quickly?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do this query:

```
SELECT 
    A.*
    , (SELECT MAX(B.Date2) FROM Tab2 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND A.Date > B.Date2) AS MaxDate
FROM
    Tab A
```

This works but it takes a lot of time to run when you have a lot of rows. Is there any quicker way to do this which give the same results?

Thank you!

Edit:

The table définitions are as follow:

```
Tab : (dd-mm-yyyy)
ID | Date
1  | 19-01-2018
1  | 14-01-2018
2  | 18-02-2019
3  | 20-03-2019

Tab2:
ID  | Date2
1   | 10-01-2018
1   | 15-01-2018
1   | 20-01-2018
2   | 15-02-2019
2   | 21-02-2019
3   | 25-03-2019
```

I want my query returns:

```
ID  | Date       | MaxDate 
1   | 19-01-2018 | 15-01-2018
1   | 14-01-2018 | 10-01-2018
2   | 18-02-2019 | 15-02-2019
3   | 20-03-2019 | NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: For performance related questions it's helpful to include table definitions and explain plans.

Comment: I edited my post with the table définitions!

Comment: Table defintions would include the column names keys etc. Try show create <table name> and cut an paste the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was unexpected for me but this query worked:

```
SELECT
    A.ID
    , A.Date
    , MAX(B.Date2) AS MaxDate
FROM
    Tab A
    left outer join Tab2 B
        on A.ID = B.ID and A.Date > B.Date2
GROUP BY
    A.ID, A.Date
;
```

I didn't know that we can put a column from a table in a group by when the column of the MAX() is in another table.